# Microsoft Test Agent temp data

Tags: automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

Where does Microsoft Test Agent or Controller store their temporary data while the test is in remote execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the remote test agent, all test data is stored in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VSEQT\QTAgent... for the service account QTAgent runs as.

Comment: FYI the same is true for the Test Controller except its the QTController subfolder...

Answer (score 0):

To change the controller's setting add "workingDirectory" to the config.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\QTController.exe.config

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vslab/thread/beef93e1-f88f-4fd3-bd4d-ba8d6cb41204/